# Thermal conductivity of metal using kinetic theory of gases model

Tags: kinetic-theory, thermal-conductivity

[image]

[image: enter image description here-2]
The first image gives the context about what i am gonna ask. Now in the second image i can understand upto the point where the book talks about kinectic theory in the second paragraph , after i am totally blank as to how it makes further calculations of energy and it also seems to deviate from the fact that heat energy is lost when it flows from A to B . It says energy of electrons at A is E and at B is E - ∆E . In this case i am unclear as to what it means by "energy transported" , i thought the energy transported to B from A was E - ∆E , since A has electrons with energy E and after loss of ∆E , remaining energy would be present with electrons at B . And then it gives another expression for energy transported from B to A , which makes no sense because at first it said heat was flowing from A to B . And then it says "net energy transported" from A to B , which again puts me into confusion as i am not able to differentiate between what the book said was "energy transported from A to B" and then "net energy transported" . Can anybody explain what is going on here?
If i follow what is being done here ,it looks like i can just double the value of any energy flowing through two different points

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0):

All right, let’s we have a rod in which energy varies from point to point in the rod continuously. So, let’s assume that at point A the energy is $E$ and just after the point A (please I don’t want to clarify what “just after” really means) there is a point B such that the energy difference between these two points is $\Delta E$.

So, any particle at A have more energy than at B by the amount $\Delta E$. When the particle move from A to B it will lose $\Delta E$ amount of energy and this will try to establish the equilibrium of energy all along the rod.

Particles will not flow spontaneously from B to A.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But what about the calculations they have made in the book , are they correct ?

Comment: As far as only those two pages are concerned it’s very hard to say that “electrons will from B to A” otherwise all calculations are correct. What are your problems?

Comment: I explained my problems in the question itself

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost Then I’m sorry I cannot answer you.

Comment: Okay , but may i know why ?

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost What is it that you haven’t understood?

Comment: what is the energy transported from A to B ?

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost $\Delta E$

Comment: How is that so , I don't understand i thought that was the energy lost

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost energy can never be lost .

Comment: I meant lost from the system or to the environment

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost No it dissipated at B and thus increases the energy at B.

Comment: Ok , then what is "net energy transported from A to B" ,?

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost $\frac{1}{6} ~n~ c^- \Delta E$

Comment: What is the difference between "net energy transported" and "energy transported" ?

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost The same thing that net force means when we have more than one force.

Comment: Exactly ! , Is there any energy transported in the opposite direction (B to A) ?

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost It’s not possible spontaneously but it is generally assumed that electrons move in all possible directions (that’s why we 1/6 factor). So, when electrons move from B to A they gain up some energy and hence reduces the temperature at A.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Comment: @Maxwell’sGhost if my answer helped you in any way or if it solved your actual problem then you can mark it “correct” and if it doesn’t (or these comments) satisfy you then you are totally free not to accept it.